# Create canvas on main process electron

Tags: electron

How can I create canvas in the main process?
I want to do https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/3148#issuecomment-153507703 but have the error on 'document is not defined' (13 line)

Answer (score 0):

There is no DOM in the main Electron process, so you can't create a canvas in that process.

Comment: It seems like there should be a workaround for this, though maybe not an easy or advisable one.